# Too many SOQL error

Tags: apex, soql, class, set

I have below code where I am getting too many soql error. Can someone please let me know where am I wrong in syntax?

```
public Integer prepareInScopeUserList(Territory t, String curHierString)
{   

    List<Id> childTerrs = terrHierTopDownMap.get(t.Id);
    Integer childCount = 0;

      Set<Id> priceBooks = new Set<Id>();
      Set<string> Splitlist= new Set<string>();
      system.debug('selCampaignFran@@'+selCampaignFran);
      Splitlist.addAll(selCampaignFran.split(';;')); 
                system.debug('Splitlist@@'+Splitlist);
                List<User> ux = [SELECT name,id,salesforce_abt__c FROM user where salesforce_abt__c  in ('AI2A','HOMEOFFICE')];
      for (User p : ux) {
        priceBooks.add(p.id);
        }

    if(childTerrs == null)
        return 0;

    for(Id childTerr: childTerrs)
    {
        Territory nt = terrMap.get(childTerr);
        if(!excludedNodes.contains(nt.Name))
        {
            childCount ++;
            hierarchyNode hn;
            if(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr) == null && (t.Name != 'iRep'  && t.Category_ID_abv__c !='PM'))
            {
                terrHierIdMap.put(childTerr,terrHierIdMap.get(t.Id));
            }
            else
            {
                Integer hierId = terrHierIdMap.keySet().size()+1;
                terrHierIdMap.put(childTerr,hierId);
            }


            Boolean userAssocTerr = False;
            if(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr) != null)
            {   //TerrUserMap.get(childTerr)  Need change here. @Saikat
              // If(pricebooks.contains(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr)))
                inScopeUsers.add(TerrUserMap.get(childTerr));     
                hn = new hierarchyNode(terrHierIdMap.get(childTerr),terrHierIdMap.get(t.Id),'User',terrMap.get(childTerr).Name,TerrUserMap.get(childTerr));              
                userAssocTerr = True;
            }
           else
            {
                if((t.Name == 'iRep' && terrMap.get(childTerr).Category_ID_abv__c != 'PM') || t.Category_ID_abv__c == 'PM')
                hn = new hierarchyNode(terrHierIdMap.get(childTerr),terrHierIdMap.get(t.Id),'Terr','<' + terrMap.get(childTerr).Name +'>',null);              
                userAssocTerr = False;
            }

            //String hierString = curHierString + '->' + nt.Name;
            String hierString =  nt.Name;
            terrHierMap.put(nt.Id,hierString);
            Integer grandChildCount = prepareInScopeUserList(nt, hierString );
            List<hierarchyNode> hierSubList = hier[hier.size()-1];
            if(hierSubList.size() >= 1000)
            {
                hierSubList = new List<hierarchyNode>();
                hier.add(hierSubList);
            }
            if(grandChildCount > 0 || userAssocTerr )
            {
                if(hn != null)
                hierSubList.add(hn);
            }    
            else 
                childCount --;    
        }
    }   
    return childCount;     
}
```

Comment: You'll need to [edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/151166/edit) to include more of your code, because what you've included so far can't cause the error that you're seeing by itself.

Comment: Still impossible for that code to cause the error by itself.

Comment: I have updated the code here with the whole method. :)

Comment: At this point, you've got a query contained in a for loop and with recursion, no less, so once you hit 100 territories, you're guaranteed to hit this governor limit. You'll want to see if you can optimize your code to query the tree more efficiently. If you have less than about 10,000 territories, you might want to just query them all and put them in a map.

Comment: @sfdcfox  This is the line it shows the error ---                                                                 List<User> ux = [SELECT name,id,salesforce_abt__c FROM user where salesforce_abt__c  in ('AI2A','HOMEOFFICE')];

Answer (score 3):

This might be caused due to recursive call happening @ the statement 
`Integer grandChildCount = prepareInScopeUserList(nt, hierString );` which might be required logically. However, the SOQL

> List ux = [SELECT name,id,salesforce_abt__c FROM user where
>   salesforce_abt__c  in ('AI2A','HOMEOFFICE')];

can be removed from the method and use the cached version instead of querying this every time as it is independent of any logic inside the method. This will avoid it getting called every time the method is getting invoked.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!